# Do ZFS zvols on Linux use the arc cache ?

Tags: linux, zfs

Is the ZFS arc cache used when doing an open() on a zvol device, or only when accessing ZFS datasets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like file systems, snapshots and clones, zvols are datasets too.

Regardless of the terminology, the ARC is used to improve read access to zvols just like most of what can be stored in the pool.